# Как реализовать проверку самопересечения ломаной?

Tags: c++, математика, координаты

пишу программу, определяющую, является ли заданная в пространстве ломаная линия самопересекающейся. С клавиатуры задаются количество звеньев и координаты вершин по порядку.
Единственный алгоритм, который пока пришёл в голову - это попарная проверка на пересечение каждого с каждым отрезка через решение системы уравнений, состоящей из двух уравнений плоскости в пространстве.
Но подозреваю, что задачу можно решить легче, поскольку само по себе решение системы с шестью переменными - не такая простая задача, а для количества звеньев в несколько тысяч (надо сгенерировать именно такие тестовые наборы) работать решение будет занимать слишком долго и много по памяти.
Какой алгоритм можно использовать?

Comment: Вам нужен [алгоритм заметающей прямой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9). Позволяет обнаружить наличие пересечений среди `n` отрезков за `O(n * log(n))`. Или [алгоритм Бентли — Оттманна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Comment: @wololo Благодарю за материал, правда, насколько я понимаю, эти алгоритмы подходят лишь для случая, когда все отрезки лежат в одной плоскости?

Comment: Мда, не заметил, что ломанная у вас заданна в пространстве, а не на плоскости :) Википедия говорит, что алгоритм можно обобщить на более высокие размерности, но пруфов не предоставляет. Немного поискав, вразумительного объяснения как применить алгоритм в трёхмерном пространстве не нашёл. Пожалуй пока что, утверждать, что можно решить вашу задачу быстрее, чем за `O(n^2)` не стану...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-то мне кажется задача легче O(n^2) не решается

например если ломанная представляет собой спираль, то никакими иными способами как проверка всех её звеньев задачу не решить

опять же может и есть какие-то оптимизации, то они лишь влияют на коэффициентик около n^2

так что да - алгоритм заключается в том чтобы

1. пройтись по всем звеньям кроме последнего -

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i ++)
   ```
2. пройти по всем звеньям от текущего до последнего -

   ```
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j ++)
   ```
3. проверить отрезки `[i]`, `[j]` на пересечение

https://e-maxx.ru/algo/segments_intersection_checking

4. в качестве оптимизации - не надо проверять отрезки, соединяющиеся с текущим, т.е.

   ```
    if ((i == j) || (abs(i - j) == 1))
        continue
   ```
5. в качестве оптимизации - не надо проверять отрезки до проверенного отрезка (поскольку их уже проверили), т.е.

   ```
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j ++)
   ```

условия 4) и 5) приводят к тому, что надо делать

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i ++)
        for (int j = i + 2; i < n; j ++)
```

Comment: У меня такая же задача. Но проблему никак решить не могу. Можете  [посмотреть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1451886/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)?

Answer (score 0):

Есть решение за O(n^2)(оно вами и описывалось). Смотрим на каждую пару отрезков, если хоть одна из этих пар пересекается, то ломаная самопересекающаяся, иначе - нет.

Особой проблемы в этом решении нет, если ограничения пару тысяч, то эта программа отработает меньше чем за секунду, а по памяти затраты будут ничтожны - нам необходимо хранить только координаты каждой точки.

```
for (int first = 0; first < n - 1; first++) {
    for (int second = 0; second < n - 1; second++) {
       if (first != second) //  говорим, что отрезки разные
          // в line содержится структурка, которая хранит координаты двух точек
          if (intersect (line[i], line[i+1], line[j], line[j+1]) {
                // нашли пересечение
          }
    }
}
```

Функцию пересечения отрезков можете подсмотреть [здесь](https://cpp.mazurok.com/mif-9/).

Comment: В функции пересечения обычно бывает 8 аргументов. У Вас тут всего 4 аргумента, примерно понимаю поечму вы так сделали, но в той ссылке с реализацией функции пересечения аргументов тоже 8. Как можно переписать эту функцию под Ваш цикл?