# Самопересечение ломаной

Tags: c++, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Перед написанием вопроса читал похожую на SO [статью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1192319/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9), но мне интересно разобраться в чем именно у меня проблема.

Пишу код для определения самопересекается ли ломаная или нет.
**Если хотя бы два звена ломаной пересекаются (в своих внутренних точках), её называют самопересекающейся.**
Для начала пишу функцию для определения пересечения двух отрезков intersect. Там использую школьную формулу прямой y = kx + b.

А далее функцию f, где проверяю каждые 2 точки 2х отрезков на пересечение.
Впринципе все работает, но код ломается при случае, когда какая-то часть ломаной не то чтобы пересекает, а просто "касается" какого-нибудь другого отрезка данной ломаной.   Например, как на тесте:
**Тест:**

```
4   
0 0   
2 2   
2 1   
1 1
```

**Код:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream fin("input.txt");
ofstream fout("output.txt");

class peresec{
    public:
        double x,y;
};

int intersect(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4)
{
    double k1, k2, b1, b2, x, y, tmp;

    if(x1>=x2) {tmp=x1; x1=x2; x2=tmp; tmp=y1; y1=y2; y2=tmp;}
    if(x3>=x4) {tmp=x3; x3=x4; x4=tmp; tmp=y3; y3=y4; y4=tmp;}

    if(y1==y2) k1=0; else k1 =  ( y2 - y1 ) / ( x2 - x1 );
    if(y3==y4) k2=0; else k2 =  ( y4 - y3 ) / ( x4 - x3 );
    if(k1 == k2) return 0;
   
    b1=y1-k1*x1;
    b2=y3-k2*x3;

    x = (b2-b1)/(k1-k2);
    y = k1*x + b1;

    if(x1<=x && x3<=x && x2>=x && x4>=x && !((x==x1 && y==y1) || (x==x2 && y==y2) || (x==x3 && y==y3) || (x==x4 && y==y4)))
        {return 1;}
    else
        return 0;
}

void f(peresec *a, int n)
{
    int flag;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            flag=intersect(a[i].x, a[i].y, a[(i + 1) % n].x, a[(i + 1) % n].y, a[j].x, a[j].y, a[(j + 1) % n].x, a[(j + 1) % n].y);
            if(flag==1) {fout << 1; return;}
        }
    if(flag == 0){fout << 0; return;}
}

int main()
{
    long long count;
    peresec *a;
     if( !(fin >> count)){fout<<0; return 0;}
     fin.seekg(0);
    
    
     fin >> count;
     if(count == 0) {fout<<0; return 0;}
    
     a = new peresec[count];
    for(int  i = 0; i < count; i++){ fin >> a[i].x; fin >> a[i].y;}

    f(a,count);

    return 0;
}
```

Также испытав провал на данном коде решил поменять логику функции intersect и сделал что-то вроде:

```
bool intersect(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4)
{
    double v1, v2, v3, v4;
    v1=(x4-x3)*(y1-y3)-(y4-y3)*(x1-x3);
    v2=(x4-x3)*(y2-y3)-(y4-y3)*(x2-x3);
    v3=(x2-x1)*(y3-y1)-(y2-y1)*(x3-x1);
    v4=(x2-x1)*(y4-y1)-(y2-y1)*(x4-x1);
    if((v1*v2<0) && (v3*v4<0)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Но и тут на данном тесте код ломается. Должно выводиться 1, иначе 0. Т.к если пересекает должно выводиться 1.

Скорее всего проблема в цикле в функции `f` и по каким вершинам прохожусь. Все уже перепробовал.

Можете объяснить почему ломается код???

Comment: На каком тесте ломается ваш код?

Comment: Я прописал в самом вверху ,выше кода

Comment: Вы хотели чтобы при касании выводился ноль. Он и выводится.

Comment: Нет, я хотел чтобы он выводил 1. Т.к если хотя бы 1 общая точка имеется, то значит пересекает. Но для таких случаев код выводит 0. @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: А если во втором коде изменить < на <= ?

Comment: @MBo я уже пробовал это,тогда код ломается чаще, чем на предыдущем коде. Например на тесте, 4 0 0 2 2 2 1 1 0.Эта ломаная самопересеч. не имеет,но код выводит 1,т.е она якобы имеет, что неверно!

Comment: Ну так соседние отрезки друг друга же касаются. Написал в ответе.

Comment: добавь в вопрос определение: что такое "самопересечение".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте второй код с `<=` вместо `<` и измените циклы так, чтобы для соседних отрезков не проводилась проверка.

```
for (int i=0; i<n-2; i++)
    for (int j=i+2; j<n-1; j++)
    {
        flag=intersect...
```

Проверочка: тест выдаёт 0 для последней точки (4,3) и 1 для последней точки (1,1) или (2,0)

```
class peresec {
public:
    double x, y;
};

bool intersect(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4)
{
    double v1, v2, v3, v4;
    v1 = (x4 - x3)*(y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3)*(x1 - x3);
    v2 = (x4 - x3)*(y2 - y3) - (y4 - y3)*(x2 - x3);
    v3 = (x2 - x1)*(y3 - y1) - (y2 - y1)*(x3 - x1);
    v4 = (x2 - x1)*(y4 - y1) - (y2 - y1)*(x4 - x1);
    if ((v1*v2 <= 0) && (v3*v4 <= 0)) return true;
    else return false;
}

void f(peresec *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
        for (int j = i + 2; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            if (intersect(a[i].x, a[i].y, a[i + 1].x, a[i + 1].y, 
                          a[j].x, a[j].y, a[j + 1].x, a[j + 1].y))
            {
                cout << i << " " << j << "  "<< 1;
                return;
            }
        }
    cout << 0;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    long long count;
    peresec *a;
    count = 4;
    a = new peresec[count];
    a[0].x = 0; a[0].y = 0;
    a[1].x = 2; a[1].y = 2;
    a[2].x = 2; a[2].y = 1;
    a[3].x = 4; a[3].y = 4;
    //a[3].x = 1;   a[3].y = 1;

    f(a, count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139517/discussion-on-answer-by-mbo--).